# SPF: softfail (domain of transitioning email does not designate 2a01:4f8:121:2062::2 as permitted sender)

Tags: centos, postfix, ipv6, spf, ipv4

I am seeing this SPF softfail for emails sent from my server, and I notice that 2a01:4f8:121:2062::2 is an IPV6 address. When I check  2a01:4f8:121:2062::2 it is translated as 0.0.0.2 ipv4, so that ipv6 address seems bogus.

I have a Centos server that does not have ipv6 configured, and I left everything at default.

How can I solve this? Should I disable ipv6 on my server? Is postfix responsible for this?  Why postfix sends mail with ipv6 when I never configured it?

As requested (I redacted my valid ipv4 address with XX)

```
[root@host ~]# ifconfig -a

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:2B:97:82
          inet addr:XX.XXX.XXX.XX  Bcast:XX.XXX.XXX.XX  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: 2a01:4f8:121:2062::2/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::4261:86ff:fe2b:9782/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5906959065 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3933424961 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6766726597523 (6.1 TiB)  TX bytes:1315274953503 (1.1 TiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:34502551 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34502551 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:37797695084 (35.2 GiB)  TX bytes:37797695084 (35.2 GiB)`
```

Comment: Just because you didn't configure it no longer means that v6 isn't configured; if your ISP provides the right infrastructure, v6 will quite happily autoconfigure itself.  Could you edit the output of `ifconfig -a` into the question?

Comment: Yep, thx. Added. My ipv6 looks bogus there as well :) Looks like I have to disable or configure ipv6...

Comment: That is not an auto-configured IPv6 address... That is an IPv6 address that Macadu (you I presume?) got from Hetzner. It seems to be your address on a Hetzner server and you probably should configure reverse DNS for it and change your SPF records. Having IPv6 is a good thing! :-)

Comment: Thx. :) Wow, this ipv6 converter showed that ipv6 address as 0.0.0.2 (http://www.subnetonline.com/pages/subnet-calculators/ipv4-to-ipv6-converter.php)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by converting an ipv6 address to ipv4.  That's not how v6 works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've established that your server is, in fact, configured for ipv6, and has a perfectly globally-valid address.  I think that disposes of the original question.

If you didn't know you were running v6, you should probably check your `ip6tables` rules, since it might be participating in all sorts of conversations you neither know about nor want!  In case further proof was wanted (I have v6 to my desktop):

```
[me@risby ~]$ telnet 2a01:4f8:121:2062::2 110
Trying 2a01:4f8:121:2062::2...
Connected to 2a01:4f8:121:2062::2.
Escape character is '^]'.
+OK Dovecot ready.
quit
+OK Logging out
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

If you'd prefer not to be running v6, you can disable it with

```
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
```

in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`, though personally I think v6 is the coming wave and you've got a great opportunity to play with it!

Comment: thx, much appreciated!

Comment: IPv6 isn't really optional anymore.

Comment: Hey, I find that behaving like an ostrich is *always* an option!